# JQuery attribute change of CSS wont work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

Im using coda-slider and changing the panels size in css file trought JQuery. Im doing this to adjust the coda-slider to the size window.
This is working fine in Firefox, but crashs Chrome and Safari.
Anyone knows how can I solve this?

This is the function

```
function resizeCentro() {
        var alt = (document.height * 0.95) + "px";
        var larg = (document.width * 0.77) + "px";

        $(".coda-slider").css('width', larg);
        $(".coda-slider").css('height', alt);

        $(".panel-wrapper").css('width', larg);
        $(".panel-wrapper").css('height', alt); 

        document.getElementById("ifInicio").width = document.width * 0.95;
        document.getElementById("ifInicio").height = document.height * 0.95;
        document.getElementById("ifInicio").src = "inicio.html";

}
```

the page can be viewed in http://www.segundafeirafilmes.com.be/prov/INDEX.html

Comment: Where's the jQuery? If you use the library, use it.

Comment: That link redirects to the root directory, which contains lots of popups, and generally looks like something to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

Use moar jQuery:

```
function resizeCentro() {
    $(".coda-slider, .panel-wrapper").width($(document).width() * 0.77;);
    $(".coda-slider, .panel-wrapper, #ifInicio").height($(document).height() * 0.95);

    $("#ifInicio").width($(document).width() * 0.95);
    $("#ifInicio").attr('src', "inicio.html");
}
```

Comment: still wont work.... still crashing in chrome and safari. In IE freeze in ajax "loading". Any other idea? I've update the page in www.segundafeirafilmes.com.br/prov/INDEX.html

Comment: seens like chrome wont support jquery. has any way to discover that? Or change the way I change the css class attribute?

Comment: Using Chrome and it works fine for me. Run it through the **W3C Unicorn Validator** to see any markup errors. Also, I doubt loading like seven JS files will help you with performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

`document.width` and `document.height` are nonstandard Netscape 4 era DOM0 that other browsers don't necessarily implement.  In particular, WebKit doesn't implement them.  And Firefox 6 will drop support for them as well.

Comment: FF6? Wow, Mozilla is really planning ahead!

Comment: Firefox 6 is planned for less than 4 months from now.  Firefox 5 is feature-complete and has been for 3 weeks, planning to ship about a month and a half from now.  Or put another way, the code in this question will stop working in Firefox come mid-August.